# 2 Auth Session with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have 2 auth area's in my website. 
 - domain/admin (admin area)
 - domain/clients (clients area)

Admin has a different model and clients has a different model.

I am using $this->Auth(); I use the following code to identify If the user is authorized.

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Client ACL
    if ($this->params['controller'] == 'clients'):
        if (isset($user) && !empty($user['business_type'])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    endif;
}
```

This works fine. The problem is, when I login to admin area and go to client area URL, It shows as I am logged in. I want to have 2 different sessions for admin area and client area.

How do I identify If a user is actually logged into admin area or client area. And I want to develop a mechanism in which an admin and client can login at the same time from same browser.

I am also using admin prefix for admin area, which is why isAthorized code for admin area is stored in AppController.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use AuthComponent::$sessionKey
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent::$sessionKey

Since you are using admin prefix, you can set a $sessionKey for admin area in  AppController.php.

Example:

```
AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Admin';
```

And in your client's controller you can create another session key for clients.

```
AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.Client';
```

This will resolve the issue.